# How can a fridge water line be connected to a water jug?

Tags: water, refrigerator

We have extremely hard ground water and it just produces tons of white flakes from the ice maker when connected to our fridge . I wanted to explore the feasibility of using 5 gallon water bottles to supply the fresh water to the fridge water line. What would it take to make it happen?

[image]

Comment: This kit made for your needs.  https://www.amazon.com/Dispenser-Dispensing-Compatible-Dispensers-Refrigerators/dp/B07QZJXPX1/ref=asc_df_B07QZJXPX1/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=343252348922&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=864097304610095550&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9010366&hvtargid=pla-760479070715&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=73036183830&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=343252348922&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=864097304610095550&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9010366&hvtargid=pla-760479070715

Comment: An inline water filter might be the way to go.

Comment: @Kris, your link is valid as an answer.

Comment: Any answer to this question, will only pertain to a small faction of your water use.  Might be better find an answer that will fix the problem at source(in the house).  All your water will have the same problem, not just the fridge.

Comment: @crip659 we do not drink the well water -- already have bottles delivered, just wanted to explore the feasibility of attaching it to the fridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Kris](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/46271/kris) for the tip, I picked up a [Bottled Water Supply Pump](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XHHG8MX/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) off Amazon:

[image]

The first one failed after a few days of operation as the pump continued to run and started leaking over the floor. I did end up also picking up a [rubber mat](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07WNHH58W/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) to place under the bottles and pump in case there are any issues in the future:

[image]

To install, I first shut off the water to the refrigerator's supply line and pulled the refrigerator out. I prepped the area with a plastic bag and rag.

[image]

In my case, my pantry was located directly behind the refrigerator which allowed me to drill into the wall and feed the power cable and water line from the pump over to the refrigerator:

[image]
[image]

I then connected the new supply line to the refrigerator and pushed it back in.

[image]

This is the final result:

[image]

Just a few final thoughts--I did not cap or close off the water supply line other than the shutoff valve for it. The pump is rather loud when running, but it allows me to use my refrigerator's ice maker and water dispenser instead of a standalone unit.

Answer (score 3):

Flojet and others make a product for that. They call theirs “bottled water system” (to help in searching for information and a supplier).

I would lean toward an established manufacturer, rather than the cheapest option on Amazon.

This is from their [product sheet](https://www.xylem.com/siteassets/brand/flojet/data-sheets/bw5000_f100-033.pdf):

[image: product usage drawing]

Answer (score -5):

Interesting idea. But I would first think through the "why". There are three advantages to water directly connected to a refrigerator:

- Filtering of the water for ice & drinking
- Automatic ice maker
- Chilled drinking water

The typical 5-gallon jugs I have seen are all either filtered, spring water or both. So no real advantage to running them through the refrigerator's filter.

There are plenty of devices designed for dispensing water from 5-gallon jugs. They range from little hand or electric pumps placed on top to full enclosed stands that provide both hot and chilled water.

So that just leaves the automatic ice maker. While convenient, under the circumstances I'd stop at a dollar store and pick up a couple of these:

[image: ice cube trays]